# Removing Left Recursion

Tags: formal-grammars, left-recursion

Im currently learning about removing left recursion. Ive watched a few youtube clips and understand the basics. For example, i can remove left recursion for the following;

$E \rightarrow E+T \mid T$

Answer

$E \rightarrow TE'$

$E'\rightarrow \varepsilon \mid +TE'$

Ive been given the following question which has sort of 3 parts to it and has me confused a lot (compared to the question example above). The question is remove the left recursion from the following grammar;

$A \rightarrow Ba$

$B \rightarrow dab \mid cB$

$C\rightarrow cB\mid Ac$

Is there another rule to follow for this, or when it has more than 1 statement as such.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: The $C$ rules can't  be reached (assuming $A$ is the starting nonterminal), should on of the $c$s be a $C$?

Comment: Please, watch your syntax. Use a capital "I"in the first person, and use apostrophy where needed: "Im" is not proper English syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The fact confusing you might be, that the given grammar isn't left recursive at all and so nothing has to be done.

To be left recursive there would have to be a nonterminal Symbol, that by a chain of productions results in a sequence of sybols starting with the same nonterminal.

This is not true for `A` since after `A -> B` the only options available are `A -> B -> dab` and `A -> B -> cB` both already starting with terminal symbols on the left.

Trivially the same goes for `B` as `B -> dab` and `B -> cB` are the only options.

Taking a look at `C` the production `C -> cB` can't cause any trouble, since the sequence is already starting with a terminal.

But even the second option `C -> Ac` is harmless, as after `C -> Ac -> Bac` the only options are `C -> Ac -> Bac -> dabac` and `C -> Ac -> Bac -> cBac`, both starting with a terminal symbol again.

Comment: Would you not substitute B into A and then C into A, resulting in one recursive function?

Comment: The only productions available for `B` are `dab` and `cB` ! Thus step 1 of your question "substitute B into A" is not possible. It is only possible to 'substitute' `B` into `dab` or `cB`.